# How can i pass all form fields using pekeup image uploader

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello here my code below i get from the web i do need to move using jquery ajax all the fields and not the file input here is the code to php page images is uploaded perfect but other normal text input is not passed to the server side

```
function UploadFile(){
  var error = true;
  if (options.theme=="bootstrap"){
    var htmlprogress = '<div class="file"><div class="filename"></div><div class="progress progress-striped"><div class="bar pekeup-progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"><span class="badge badge-info"></span></div></div></div>';
  }
  if (options.theme=="custom"){
    var htmlprogress = '<div class="file"><div class="filename"></div><div class="progress-pekeupload"><div class="bar-pekeupload pekeup-progress-bar" style="width: 0%;"><span></span></div></div></div>';
  }
  obj.next('a').next('div').prepend(htmlprogress);
  var formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(options.field, obj[0].files[0]);
  formData.append('data', options.data);
  $.ajax({
        url: options.url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
                // dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            alert(data)
          var percent = 100;
          obj.next('a').next('div').find('.pekeup-progress-bar:first').width(percent+'%');
            obj.next('a').next('div').find('.pekeup-progress-bar:first').text(percent+"%");
            if (data==1){
              if (options.multi==false){
                obj.attr('disabled','disabled');
              }
              options.onFileSuccess(file,data);
            }
            else{
              options.onFileError(file,data);
              obj.next('a').next('div').find('.file:first').remove();
              if((options.theme == "bootstrap")&&(options.showErrorAlerts==true)){
                obj.next('a').next('div').prepend('<div class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> '+data+'</div>');
                bootstrapclosenotification();
              }
              if((options.theme == "custom")&&(options.showErrorAlerts==true)){

                obj.next('a').next('div').prepend('<div class="alert-pekeupload"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button> '+data+'</div>');
                customclosenotification();
              }
              error = false;
            }
        },
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
              myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
              if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
          },
        cache: false,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false
      });
  return error;
}
```

Comment: try replacing `var formData = new FormData();` with `var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('your_form_id'));`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
`var formData = new FormData();`
```

with following

```
`var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('put_your_form_id_here'));`
```

You can read more  here ( Browse for Sending files using a FormData object topic )
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects